# The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'MyField' on type 'Class1' is not valid

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, one-to-many

Struggling on a Foreign key with Entity Framework (1 to many relationship).

class1:

```
 public partial class Class1
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
       [ForeignKey("Class2_Id")]
        public Class2 Class2{ get; set; }
...}

Class2:
 public partial class Class2
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Class1> Stuff{ get; set; }
...}
```

1)I tried with fluentAPI:
1st try:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Class2>().HasMany<Class1>(p => p.Stuff).WithOptional().Map(m => m.MapKey("Class2_Id")).WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

2nd try:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Class1>().HasRequired(i => i.Class2).WithMany().Map(m => m.MapKey("Class2_Id"));
```

2)without fluentAPI:
I declared the concerned `Class2` field this way:

```
[Column("Class2")]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Even (which probably makes no sense):

```
[ForeignKey("Class2")]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

I always get this error:

> The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'Class2' on type 'Class1' is not valid. The foreign key name 'Class2_Id' was not found on the
>   dependent type 'Class1'. The Name value should be a comma separated
>   list of foreign key property names.

Any idea what is wrong?

thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your fluent api configurations you are defining a unidirectional relationship, so the correct way would be:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Class2>().HasMany(p => p.Stuff)
                             .WithOptional(c=>c.Class2)
                             .Map(m => m.MapKey("Class2_Id"))
                             .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

`MapKey` method is used when you don't want to have the foreign key as a property in your model class.

Use `ForeignKey` attribute when you represent the FK column as a property of your entity:

```
public partial class Class1
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? Class2_Id{ get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Class2_Id")]
    public Class2 Class2{ get; set; }
}
```

In this last case your relationship configuration using Fluent Api would be:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Class2>().HasMany(p => p.Stuff)
                             .WithOptional(c=>c.Class2)
                             .HasForeignKey(c=>c.Class2_Id))
                             .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

Comment: Great explanation octavioccl. I thank you very much!